# How do I put values od dataframe column in 2d matrix?

Tags: pandas, numpy, matrix, dataframe

I have the pandas dataframe with 3 columns `value`, `row_index`, `column_index`. I would like to create a matrix, where values of dataframe placed at relevant rows and columns and unknown elements are zeros.

I have made a for-cycle like this:

```
N_rows = df.row_index.max()
N_cols = df.column_index.max()
A = np.zeros((N_rows, N_cols))
for i in df.row_index:
    for j in df.column_index:
        np.put(A, i*N_cols+j, df['value'][(df.row_index==i) & 
                                          (df.column_index==j)])
```

but it works very slow.

How can I do it faster?

Comment: Try `array = df.fillna(0).values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modifying a minor part in @jezrael's solution. You can actually use Pandas `as_matrix()` functions to get the arrays:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[2,4,5],
                   'row_index':[2,3,4],
                   'col_index':[0,2,3]})

df.pivot('row_index', 'col_index', 'value').fillna(0).as_matrix()
# array([[ 2.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  4.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  5.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and for missing values of columns and rows add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), last for numpy array add [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[2,4,5],
                   'row_index':[2,3,4],
                   'col_index':[0,2,3]})

print (df)
   col_index  row_index  value
0          0          2      2
1          2          3      4
2          3          4      5

rows = np.arange(df.row_index.max()+1)
cols = np.arange(df.col_index.max()+1)

print (df.pivot('row_index', 'col_index', 'value')
         .fillna(0)
         .reindex(index=rows, columns=cols, fill_value=0))
col_index    0    1    2    3
row_index                    
0          0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1          0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2          2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3          0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0
4          0.0  0.0  0.0  5.0

a = df.pivot('row_index', 'col_index', 'value')
      .fillna(0)
      .reindex(index=rows, columns=cols, fill_value=0)
      .values
print (a)
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  5.]]
```

Another solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (df.set_index(['row_index', 'col_index'])['value']
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reindex(index=rows, columns=cols, fill_value=0))

col_index  0  1  2  3
row_index            
0          0  0  0  0
1          0  0  0  0
2          2  0  0  0
3          0  0  4  0
4          0  0  0  5


a = df.set_index(['row_index', 'col_index'])['value']
      .unstack(fill_value=0)
      .reindex(index=rows, columns=cols, fill_value=0)
      .values
print (a)
 [[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 4 0]
 [0 0 0 5]]
```